# RSA decryption from .NET using PHP

Tags: php, rsa

I am not sure where to post this so I am starting here and hoping for the best. I have a public and private key generated for .NET. The keys have (Modulus, Exponent, etc...). I sent the public key to a third party and they used it to encrypt passwords in a database. I downloaded the encrypted passwords and now I need to decrypt them on my end. The issue comes in  when it has to be decrypted on a unix server. I do not care if I use php, java or any other language as long as it works on the unix box. I am a complete rookie to RSA keys and would appreciate any help or even a direction on where I "should" post this. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have a look at the PHP OpenSSL extension for starters: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Comment: How did you retrieve the keys from .NET? What format are they in?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have tried but have failed to get anything to work with openssl.

Comment: Gregs - Here is a sample of the format for the keys I am working with: Below are the Public and Private key values that were generated.


Public key:
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>oRykN+m+Znvoy/CSiXcK7024ljy/pFQHikH/eHYhuzzumUXDoxKBrKUd7+
5NiyFF480SiCgRP/VDk9mrGCEAmJgklUmbs/Bo9sTOYdTqWDkqt2FkH5e5wOk3qQ7f0WWcPq53fLZeCx
XTWzFhmib6BJBEChs2N7gfIfXsp+Yi6Xc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyVal
ue>

Comment: Private Key: <RSAKeyValue><D>Fs+WVLBMm/gJQu7B4KKxMqafbu4U+DBJjQLBKA4ZwofjBGKDS5BwOcB7F6B27C7+
1T0Q1aROpO6V7dYQym7JxZeT9q2DF4OQu62BRwz6cG4xfQ4oQZWjbxWQNj2IyzGG9/JPHk2LQc2BGEat
JyLXkmdKSuPz1i5H85Pg7WGR15E=</D><DP>tY60JQ26IojR6sFZ9DCXJKYENFa1jPAru+08n+cX7u0+
CxfVcr/XcevZ2QvbR5dYKUJrmfcB4dK/1MLoaqiMRw==</DP><DQ>RInts3Wwxi9KdBo+IOq6Jq+g0iq
vSANPOX2ZWRdKZyqdqm70ftnDmW35dYlvDdKaAGpl6u+xbGXY2m5gy3hPMQ==</DQ><InverseQ>r9EL
6x7mDf28qLMjn2Qwva/PKoId1EDJR/gP5pHsyOxtXxomedebFIqTlZ+0Ry8jn/+kr47w3dZZ5oxGftti
fg==</InverseQ>

Comment: rest os private key: <P>1rJ3LuOHN/v+HQhn0/aS4vul5lcLIEEm8d/YAMsPCRnBptlfSrsFxwrLQfS9a8
0FgRX8l8L4eE4XI86GUu/2Pw==</P><Q>wBstUgrGpmAiuOhPTWp5zsA1Rgsu9IhHnNCUctX5SFZqWB7
+o+c9PNNiHa4y1k3SF72tVLGtfg3aS8y1VDTuyQ==</Q></RSAKeyValue>

Answer (score 2):

The values appear to be base64 encoded.  You could use [phpseclib's pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) and do something like this to load the public key:

```
$rsa->loadKey(array('modulus' => $modulus, 'exponent' => $exponent), CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);
```

For the private key...  maybe you could do something like..

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->modulus = $modulus;
$rsa->publicExponent = $exponent;
$rsa->exponents = array(1=> $dp, $dq)
$rsa->coefficients = array(2 => $inverseq);
$rsa->primes = array(1 => $p, $q);
```

Or something like that - I haven't tested the code, but a cursory glance of phpseclib's code suggests that'll work.

Comment: I really appreciate the help notedshow. I have read the documentation and must confess that I am well versed in php, I am lost when it comes to RSA and the implementation. I have the Private key, Public Key and the encrypted password, but How do I use what you are showing me against the encrypted password? Sorry in advance for my ignorance.

Answer (score -1):

There is a nice article about using .NET's key format with PHP:
[Using PHP to encrypt/decryp/sign/verify data with .NET XML RSA key](http://www.codeblog.co.uk/2011/08/02/web-development/using-php-to-encrypt-decrypt-sign-verify-data-with-a-net-generated-xml-rsa-key/)

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**